# Filter can't access Cookies on startup

Tags: jsp, session, cookies, servlet-filters, tomcat8

I implemented a filter-class for checking if a user is already logged in.

During the login a cookie and a database-entry are created and the Filter-Class either checks if some session-attributes are set or if the cookie is equivalent with the database-records.

Usually it works fine but after a Tomcat-Restart I have to log in again. Same goes as I shut down the PC.

- First I was in the impression maybe there had been an unnoticed change in the session which was updated in the database but there were no clues for this theory.
- My next assumption was the Session-ID was updated and the database didn't catch up - yet after implementing a Session-ID-History the update went smooth always and the filter could distinguish as supposed.
- Now I checked if all the cookies existed, and according to Firefox they do. (checked during the same time as I do the debug)

[image: Cookies exist]

I stared to debug my filter-class and figured out there is only one cookie in existence:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.

    boolean positive = false;

    //is ok
    if (req.getSession().getAttribute("Benutzername") != null && req.getSession().getAttribute("BenID") != null) {
        positive = true;
    }
    if (!positive) {
        cookies.GetCookie gc = new cookies.GetCookie(req.getCookies());
        /**
        Checks...
        **/
    }
    try {
            fc.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (NullPointerException nupo) {
            Logger.getLogger(SessionCheckFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, nupo);
            if (request == null) {
                Logger.getLogger(SessionCheckFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Request is null");
            }
            if (response == null) {
                Logger.getLogger(SessionCheckFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Response is null");
            }

        }
    }
```

The line `req.getCookies()` returns just the cookie JSESSIONID. 
After I logged in again all cookies are accessible again... How is this possible?

Here's the web.xml too, can it be I forgot something...? I'm using Tomcat 8.0.15.0 and the JDK 1.8, as Java EE 7 Web.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <filter>
        <description>Sollte den Login überprüfen</description>
        <filter-name>Loginpruefung</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.SessionCheckFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Loginpruefung</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/filter/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/sqlserv</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
    <jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
</web-app>
```